# Puppet systemctl start puppetserver error on Cloud - CentOS7

Tags: error-handling, server, google-cloud-platform, puppet, centos7

I got an error for the first time..

```
systemctl start puppetserver
```

---

Job for puppetserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status puppe
tserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

---

```
systemctl status puppetserver.service

● puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Sat 2018-02-03 13:48:10 EET; 2min 10s ago
  Control: 13014 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           ├─13014 bash /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/cli/apps/start
           └─13021 /usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger...
Feb 03 13:48:10 puppetmaster systemd[1]: puppetserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 03 13:48:10 puppetmaster systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...
```

and *journalctl -xe

```
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$eval5068$fn__5069$G__5055__5
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13835$run_lifecycle_fn_B
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13835$run_lifecycle_fn_B
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13864$run_lifecycle_fns_
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13864$run_lifecycle_fns_
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14346$build_app_STAR___1
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval14392$boot_services_for_
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core$partial$fn__4761.invoke(core.clj:2521)
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13905$initialize_lifecyc
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$eval13905$initialize_lifecyc
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeSta
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(io
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.i
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.i
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__12043.invoke(async.clj:3
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__11989$fn__11992.invoke(async.cl
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6799$fn
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolEx
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolE
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster puppetserver[13373]: Background process 13380 exited before start had completed
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: Failed to start puppetserver Service.
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit puppetserver.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: Unit puppetserver.service entered failed state.
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: puppetserver.service failed.
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: puppetserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 03 13:52:47 puppetmaster systemd[1]: Starting puppetserver Service...
-- Subject: Unit puppetserver.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit puppetserver.service has begun starting up.
```

maybe is a problem in what I configured on?:  `vi /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btw..
I changed the JAVA_ARGS=" 2g to 512m ''

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger"
```

now is running:

```
systemctl status puppetserver
● puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-02-03 14:41:15 EET; 46s ago
  Process: 20172 ExecStop=/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/bin/puppetserver stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20295 ExecStart=/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/bin/puppetserver start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20302 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           └─20302 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -Djava.s...
```

Comment: refer to https://puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/5.3/known_issues.html the above config in file either /etc/sysconfig/puppetserver or /etc/default/puppetserver